# How to convert a Tensorflow session to a keras model object?

Tags: tensorflow, session, keras, deep-learning

Suppose I have a pre-trained model stored in a Tensorflow checkpoint. I'd like to convert it into a Keras model. I can load the checkpoint into a TF session alright but that's where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to create a Keras model using TF checkpoint, but you can copy it's weights to the already created Keras model.

Checkout this. https://github.com/yuyang-huang/keras-inception-resnet-v2

The `extract_weights.py` is to save the TF weights to numpy array, while `load_weights.py` is for load the `npy` file to the Keras model.

For more reference, this is how I implement it https://github.com/DableUTeeF/keras-efficientnet/tree/master/keras_efficientnet.